# for loop is pending not to execute

Tags: bash, find

I tried to find all the lines containing word `heaq` in *.md file

```
$  for i in $(find . -regex ".*md$"); do grep -i "heaq"; done
#pending
#pending
```

However, it constantly pending there.

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: you're not passing any file argument to grep, so grep will expect its input from stdin; enter a line of the form 'yeah heaq' when it's "pending" and grep will kindly print it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `grep` that is "pending".  When `grep` is run without a filename to read from, it will read standard input.  If you don't provide any data on standard input, it will appear to "hang".

You are also looping over the output of `find`.  This is inelegant (the loop won't run until all pathnames has been found by `find`) and dangerous (the pathnames will be split on whitespaces and the shell will perform filename globbing on them).

Instead, if you want to run `grep` on all files with a particular filename suffix:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -exec grep -iF 'heaq' {} +
```

I've changed the `-regex` thing to a standard `-name` test with a pattern that matches only filenames with a `.md` filename suffix.  I've also added `-type f` as it only makes sense to run `grep` on regular files (you may possibly want to change `-type f` to `! -type d` to run it on any non-directory instead).

The `grep` is executed through `-exec` in batches on the found pathnames. I'm using `-F` with `grep` as we are matching a string, not a regular expression.  You may want to add `-w` if you want to match a word rather than any substring.

Related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass the file name to `grep`

so like

```
$ for i in $(find . -regex ".*md$"); do grep -i "heaq" $i; done
```

you can also use

```
% grep -i -n "heaq" $(find . -regex ".*md$")
```

`-n` makes grep prints out matching line numbers

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis; however looping over `find` output in this manner is going to be fragile - better to use something like `find . -regex ".*md$" -exec grep -i "heaq" {} ';'` (or `find . -regex ".*md$" -exec grep -i "heaq" {} +` if supported). Also worth pointing out that `-regex` is overkill here - a simple `-name "*.md"` glob match should be sufficient

Comment: @steeldriver Any `find` implementation that has the non-standard `-regex` is bound to have the standard `-exec ... {} +`.